# Existing project which is having pom.xml file in it

Tags: maven-2

I have been given an existing project which is consisting of pom.xml file in it .
Can we manually run the pom.xml file , to create a war file and deploy it into Tomcat WEB Apps

Please tell me how to do this .

Thank you very much for reading .

(And also in our existing Application , we are having more than one POM.xml files in it )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have (Maven)[http://maven.apache.org/] installed and set your environment variables for JAVA_HOME and M2_HOME or M3_HOME based on the version of Maven.
From the command line, navigate to the location that has the pom.xml file.
Type: `mvn clean install`.
This will create a target folder that has the .war in it.
Take the .war file and install in Tomcat.
Hope this helps.
Thanks...

Comment: that certainly helped thank you very much , Now as i am using Eclipse as my IDE , can i put break points in my source and debug in this case ??

Comment: You certainly can. Just make sure that you start Tomcat in DEBUG mode. Thanks...FYI Eclipse has a maven plugin called m2eclipse. Check it out.